# Receive voip push notification after reboot

Tags: ios, push-notification

After implementing voip push notification with pushkit, the following handler can be called when I send a notification to device.

```
- (void)pushRegistry:(PKPushRegistry *)registry didReceiveIncomingPushWithPayload:(PKPushPayload *)payload forType:(NSString *)type
```

It works when app is in the background or killed by user. However, it doesn't work after rebooting iOS.

My question is that does pushkit work after rebooting?

Comment: have you added the required fields in info.plist(ie show the app as voip) for back ground action ?. Im pretty sure that if the background mode is added in info.plist , it will be automatically started at boot.

Comment: I initialize bluetooth manager in didReceiveIncomingPushWithPayload. Looks like it make pushkit work incorrectly. After removing the bluetooth code, it works correctly.